# Converting a utf16 csv to array

Tags: python, csv, utf-8, utf-16

I've tried to convert a CSV file coded in UTF-16 (exported by another program) to a simple array in Python 2.7 with very few luck.

Here's the nearest solution I've found:

```
from io import BytesIO
with open ('c:\\pfm\\bdh.txt','rb') as f:
    x = f.read().decode('UTF-16').encode('UTF-8')
        for line in csv.reader(BytesIO(x)):
            print line
```

This code returns:

> ['    \tNombre\tEtiqueta\tExtensi\xc3\xb3n de archivo\tTama\xc3\xb1ol\xc3\xb3gico\tCategor\xc3\xada']
>   ['1\tnom1\tetq1\text1 ...

What I'm trying to get it's something like this:

```
[['','Nombre','Etiqueta','Extensión de archivo','Tamaño lógico','Categoría']
 ['1','nom1','etq1','ext1','123','cat1']
 ['2','nom2','etq2','ext2','456','cat2']]
```

So, I'd need to convert those hexadecimal chars to latin typos (as: á,é,í,ó,ú, or ñ), and those tab-separated strings into arrays fields.

Do I really need to use dictionaries for the first part? I think there should be an easier solution, as I can see and write all these characater by keyboard.

For the second part, I think the CSV library won't help in this case, as I read it can't manage UTF-16 yet.

Could you give me a hand? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### ITEM #1: The hexadecimal characters

You are getting the:

```
[' \tNombre\tEtiqueta\tExtensi\xc3\xb3n de archivo\tTama\xc3\xb1ol\xc3\xb3gico\tCategor\xc3\xada']
```

output because you are printing a `list`. The behaviour of the list is to print the representation of each item. That is, it is the equivalent of:

```
print('[{0}]'.format(','.join[repr(item) for item in lst]))
```

If you use `print(line[0])` you will get the output of the line.

#### ITEM #2: The output

The problem here is that the csv parser is not parsing the content as a tab-separated file, but a comma-separated file. You can fix this by using:

```
for line in csv.reader(BytesIO(s), delimiter='\t'):
    print(line)
```

instead.

This will give you the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Processing a UTF-16 file with the `csv` module in Python 2 can indeed be a pain. Re-encoding to UTF-8 works, but you then still need to *decode* the resulting columns to produce `unicode` values.

Note also that your data appears to be *tab delimited*; the `csv.reader()` by default uses commas, not tabs, to separate columns. You'll need to configure it to use tabs instead by setting `delimiter='\t'` when constructing the reader.

Use `io.open()` to read UTF-16 and produce `unicode` lines. You can then use [`codecs.iterencode()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.iterencode) to translate the decoded `unicode` values from the UTF-16 file to UTF-8.

To decode the rows back to `unicode` values, you could use an extra generator to do so as you iterate:

```
import csv
import codecs
import io


def row_decode(reader, encoding='utf8'):
    for row in reader:
        yield [col.decode('utf8') for col in row]


with io.open('c:\\pfm\\bdh.txt', encoding='utf16') as f:
    wrapped = codecs.iterencode(f, 'utf8')
    reader = csv.reader(wrapped, delimiter='\t')
    for row in row_decode(reader):
        print row
```

Each line will *still* use `repr()` on each contained value, which means that you'll see Python string literal syntax to represent strings. Any non-printable or non-ASCII codepoint will be represented by an escape code:

```
>>> [u'', u'Nombre', u'Etiqueta', u'Extensión de archivo', u'Tamaño lógico', u'Categoría']
[u'', u'Nombre', u'Etiqueta', u'Extensi\xf3n de archivo', u'Tama\xf1o l\xf3gico', u'Categor\xeda']
```

This is *normal*; the output is meant to be useful as a debugging aid and can be pasted back into any Python session to reproduce the original value, without worrying about terminal encodings.

For example, `ó` is represented as `\xf3`, representing the Unicode codepoint [U+00F3 LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH ACUTE](http://codepoints.net/U+00F3). If you were to *print* this one column, Python will encode the Unicode string to bytes matching your terminal encoding, resulting in your terminal showing you the correct string again:

```
>>> u'Extensi\xf3n de archivo'
u'Extensi\xf3n de archivo'
>>> print u'Extensi\xf3n de archivo'
Extensión de archivo
```

Demo:

```
>>> import csv, codecs, io
>>> io.open('/tmp/demo.csv', 'w', encoding='utf16').write(u'''\
...  \tNombre\tEtiqueta\tExtensi\xf3n de archivo\tTama\xf1o l\xf3gico\tCategor\xeda
... ''')
63L
>>> def row_decode(reader, encoding='utf8'):
...     for row in reader:
...         yield [col.decode('utf8') for col in row]
... 
>>> with io.open('/tmp/demo.csv',  encoding='utf16') as f:
...     wrapped = codecs.iterencode(f, 'utf8')
...     reader = csv.reader(wrapped, delimiter='\t')
...     for row in row_decode(reader):
...         print row
... 
[u' ', u'Nombre', u'Etiqueta', u'Extensi\xf3n de archivo', u'Tama\xf1o l\xf3gico', u'Categor\xeda']
>>> # the row is displayed using repr() for each column; the values are correct:
... 
>>> print row[3], row[4], row[5]
Extensión de archivo Tamaño lógico Categoría
```